cordova electron problem working with cordova-plugin-file and cordova plugin-filtransfer
I i'm try to use cordova-plugin-file in electon project but can working with filesystem
for example I use next code:
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, (fileSystem) => {
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("MyFiles", { create: true }, (dirEntry) => {
        dirEntry.getFile("test.txt", { create: true, exclusive: false }, (fileEntry) => {
            // Use the fileEntry to write/read from the file.
        }, (err) => { console.error("getFile", err); });
    }, (err) => { console.error("getDirectory", err); });
}, (err) => { console.error("requestFileSystem", err); });

But get next error:
Error: exec proxy not found for :: File :: requestFileSystem
util.js:344 onErrorLoadFs FileError {code: 'Missing Command Error'}

Where my mistake?

Also I have this log Error: exec proxy not found for :: File :: requestFileSystem
